# VSTS UI query to return User Stories with only new tasks

Tags: azure-devops

I want to return all user stories with tasks that are new using the query UI.  If it has tasks that are Active, Closed, etc. it does not qualify.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query: (Reference the sreenshot)

Type of query : `Work items and direct links`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done. You can either get all User Story work items with or without New tasks or all items that have(n't) got Active, Closed etc tasks.

You can't have both.